# Show that $U(8)$ is Isomorphic to $U(12)$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

> Question: Show that $U(8)$ is Isomorphic to $U(12)$

The groups are:

$U\left ( 8 \right )=\left \{ 1,3,5,7 \right \}$

$U\left ( 12 \right )=\left \{ 1,5,7,11 \right \}$

I think there is a bit of subtle point that I am not fully understanding about isomorphism which is hindering my progress. The solution mentions about the order of an element but I do not understand how that is pivotal to solving this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not necessary but it helps. Maybe you should take a closer look at what it actually says about the order of the elements and how it uses it for the solution.

Comment: Have you computed the orders of any elements? You don't mention it. If not, please do so.

Comment: The square of every element in U(8) equals to 1 mod 8. Hence, I argue the order of every element in U(8) is 2.

Comment: You can also show that both are isomorphic to $C_2\times C_2$, where $C_k$ is the cyclic group of order $k$.

Comment: Combine [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1043723/11619) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1677456/11619).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen My issue is with defining a map

Comment: If $V_4=\{1,a,b,c\}$ is the Klein 4-group, and $f:U(8)\to V_4$ and $g:U(12)\to V_4$ are isomorphisms, then the map you need is $g^{-1}\circ f$. Just calculate it one element at a time. Don't look for a magic arithmetic formula. That is a waste of time. Mind you, there are no less than six different isomorphisms between the two groups. You have a lot of freedom in choosing the images of individual elements.

Comment: And, if you don't want to go via $V_4$ (may be a good idea), then start experimenting. If $\phi$ is to be an isomorphism, what does it say about $\phi(1)$? If you guess what $\phi(3)$ might be, what does that tell you about $\phi(3^2)$ (that's where the stuff about orders comes from). After you have settled on a guess for $\phi(3)$, then try and find a matching $\phi(5)$. What does that tell you about $\phi(3\cdot5)$? In the end look at group tables to check that the homomorphic condition is satisfied everywhere.

Comment: Have you tried writing down the Cayley table for both $U(8)$ and $U(12)$?

Comment: Yes I have. The Cayley table for both groups are symmetric about the diagonal. Note that a group is Abelian IFF the Cayley table for that group is symmetric about the diagonal.@Merkh

Comment: Obviously, $\phi(1)$ =1 by properties of homomorphism.@JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I am not getting anywhere. I am unable to determine what $\phi(3)$ is

Comment: $\phi(1)$ is right. Recall that I told you that the isomorphism is not unique! You can actually pick $\phi(3)$ any which way you want!

Comment: Let me attempt the question once again tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

The preferred approach would be to explicitly construct that isomorphism, but since the problem suggests basing the proof around the concept of "order of an element", let us do so then.

The crucial thing here is that both groups are of order $4$, and a simple theorem says that there exist only two classes of groups of order $4$: those isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$ (also known as "the Klein group") and those isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_4$. Notice that in $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$ all the elements are of order $2$, while in $\Bbb Z_4$ there are elements of order $4$.

It is now a matter of simple calculations to check that in your groups all the elements have order $2$, therefore they cannot be isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_4$, hence by the above considerations they must be isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$, hence isomorphic between themselves. (Notice that we don't have an explicit formula for this isomorphism - but neither are we required to find it.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $F:U(8) \rightarrow U(12)$ be such that
$F(1)=1´;
F(3)=11´;
F(5)=5´;
F(7)=7´$. Note that $ F$ is bijective, to
show that $F$ is an isomorphism we only need to show that $F$ is indeed operation preserving.Observe

$F(1*n)=F(n) = F(n)*1'=F(n)*F(1)$ for all $n \in U(8)$;
$F(3*5)=F(7)=7'=11'*5'=F(3)*F(5);\\ F(5*7)=F(35)=F(3)=11´=5´*7´=F(5)*F(7); \\ F(3*7)=F(21)=F(5)=5´=11´*7´=F(3)*F(7). $

(Where $*$ reffers for respective group operations)

$\Rightarrow F$ is a homomorphism & F is bijective
$\Rightarrow F$ is an isomorphism
$\Rightarrow U (8) \cong U(12).$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Please use Mathjax to format your responses

Comment: note that the elements of U(8) and U(12) are class module 8 and module 12 respectively.